# "Pander to" vs. "cater to"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "pander to" and "cater to"?

I've googled both of them, but they seem pretty much same.

Can anybody give me some examples?

Comment: One caters to needs and requests and panders to demands and expectations.

Comment: *Pandering* is bad. *Catering* is good.

Comment: Good catering stills my hunger

Answer (score 2):

Strictly, pandering always involves base or vulgar motives on the part of the panderer and often the client, too.

Broadly, a panderer provides goods or services not philanthropically but for personal gain and often in dubious circumstances.

Specifically, a panderer is to a pimp as a client is to a prostitute.

Comment: I disagree: a panderer _is_ a pimp. I can't even imagine an answer to the question "What is to a pimp as a client is to a prostitute?"

Comment: I almost see what you mean and I think you will be pressed to find a solid example… 

Pimps are supposed to protect, provide for and protect psrotitutes, which does make the prostitute a generally get themselves a bad name

Comment: Well, most people won't ask but if you stroll round the back streets and a suspicious-looking character in a zoot suit asks whether you’d like some fun with his pretty little friend I suggest he’s pimping her, not pandering to you.

If you collar a local urchin and ask him to get you off with his sister, my suggestion is that you hope he will pander for you, even if he’s also pimping for her.

If you seek out a bunch of sorry-looking thugs and set them to kidnap someone’s sister for salacious schemes of your own, I suggest that they will be pandering to your desires, not pimping for her.